# How to force gravity when jump(space) and limit?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to force gravity when Char jumps, now when I push space, object just flys in the sky unlimit, how to make like usual jump and force gravity when it lands

**Code of my character:**

```js
 horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        vertical   = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        
        rigidBody.AddForce((transform.forward * vertical) * speed / Time.deltaTime);
        rigidBody.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero * speed / Time.deltaTime;
        rigidBody.MoveRotation(rigidBody.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0f, horizontal, 0f) * 5f));

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)) {
            rigidBody.AddForce(0, 50, 0, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: What language is the code in? You should tag that too.

Comment: Have you enabled gravity on the rigidbody component of your game object in the inspector menu?

Comment: @JoelSmith, yes, It works, but object lands too slow

Comment: Does [this article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/uktechnet/2015/07/22/5-common-mistakes-made-in-unity/) provide any insight?

Answer (score 1):

Use gravity. Gravity power is value inside engine. Use `Physics.gravity = new Vector3(0F, -Your_Wandet_Speed_F, 0F);` To set gravity power from script. You can go to `Edit -> Project Settings -> Physics` and set gravity from editor.

And one more thing. Use `Input.GetKeyDown` instead `Input.GetKey`. It will work better

Good luck with your project.

-Garrom